# Replace break tags with other set of break tags using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I was wondering if there was a way in JavaScript to replace

```
<br><br />
```

tags with just the

```
<br />
```

tag in a string using a regular expression?

Instead of

```
"Hello world."<br><br />"The light is bright."<br><br />
```

I would like to have something like

```
"Hello world."<br />"The light is bright."<br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend the [DOM approach from charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654490/6243352), but here's a regex option for completeness:

```js
const html = '"Hello world."<br><br />"The light is bright."<br><br />';
const fixed = html.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>)+/gi, "<br />");
console.log(fixed);
```

The regex locates runs of `<br>` tags, defined as a case-insensitive `<br` followed by any number of optional spaces, an optional `/` character and a closing bracket `>` and replaces the run with a single self-closing `<br />`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the dom for this is most efficient approach . The dom is a much better html parser than regex

```js
const str =  "Hello world.<br><br />The light is bright.<br><br />"

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;

const brs = div.getElementsByTagName('br');

for(let i = brs.length-1; i>=0; i--){
   var el = brs[i],
   prevSib = el.previousSibling;
   if(prevSib.tagName ==='BR'){
       el.remove()
   }  
}

console.log(div.innerHTML);
```